buscador en php con mysql exacto
el problema es que cuando realizo una busqueda "cartera marron" me muestra tooodass los productos que contengan la palabra cartera y la palabra marron, es decir me muestra las carteras marrones y tambien los monederos marrones y las carteras negras. ya he echo muchisimas pruebas pero no logro que el buscador solo me muestre "cartera marron" cabe destacar que los productos estan registrado de la siguiente manera : CARTERA COACH MOD. 3974-2# MARRÓN
mi codigo de busqueda es:
<?php
// Obtener términos de búsqueda
if (isset($_POST['busqueda'])) {
$busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
$busqueda = trim($busqueda); // Elimina espacios en blanco alrededor
$palabras = explode(" ", $busqueda); // Dividir en palabras

if (empty($palabras)) {
    echo "Por favor, ingresa un término de búsqueda.";
    exit;
}

$primera_palabra = array_shift($palabras); // Extraer la primera palabra

$resultados = []; // Array para almacenar todos los resultados
$visto = []; // Inicializar el array visto para evitar duplicados

// Buscar productos que contengan la primera palabra
$consulta_primera_palabra = $conexion->prepare("SELECT *, 'primera_palabra' AS tipo FROM 
productos WHERE activo=1 AND (nombre LIKE ? OR codigo LIKE ?)");
$primera_palabra_like = "%$primera_palabra%";
$consulta_primera_palabra->bind_param("ss", $primera_palabra_like, $primera_palabra_like);
$consulta_primera_palabra->execute();
$resultado_primera_palabra = $consulta_primera_palabra->get_result();

while ($data = $resultado_primera_palabra->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Añadir resultados con la primera palabra al array de resultados
    $resultados[$data['id']] = $data; // Usar ID como clave para evitar duplicados
}

// Buscar productos que contengan las palabras restantes
if (!empty($palabras)) {
    $condiciones = [];
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        $palabra = $conexion->real_escape_string($palabra); // Escapar caracteres especiales
        $condiciones[] = "(activo=1 AND (codigo LIKE '%$palabra%' OR nombre LIKE 
  '%$palabra%'))";
    }
    $consulta_independiente = "SELECT *, 'independiente' AS tipo FROM productos WHERE " . 
    implode(" OR ", $condiciones);
    $resultado_independiente = $conexion->query($consulta_independiente);

    while ($data = $resultado_independiente->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Evitar duplicados en el array de resultados
        if (!isset($resultados[$data['id']])) {
            $resultados[$data['id']] = $data; // Usar ID como clave para evitar duplicados
        }
       }
     }

    // Ordenar resultados para mostrar primero los productos que contienen la primera palabra
     usort($resultados, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['tipo'] === 'primera_palabra' && $b['tipo'] === 'independiente') {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a['tipo'] === 'independiente' && $b['tipo'] === 'primera_palabra') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    });

    // Mostrar los resultados
    if (!empty($resultados)) {
    foreach ($resultados as $data) {
        // Si ya se ha mostrado este producto, no mostrarlo de nuevo
        if (!in_array($data["id"], $visto)) {
            $visto[] = $data["id"]; // Marcar el producto como visto
            ?>


Lo que estas diciendo no es un problema.. es exactamente como esta programado y lo que pediste que hiciera....

ah ok! @gbianchi

Pienso que tu problema es más SQL que PHP. Para aislar el problema, supongamos que tienes el siguiente dataset:
INSERT INTO productos (id, codigo, descripcion) VALUES 
(1, '123450', 'CARTERA MEDIANA 521 MARRÓN'),
(2, '123451', 'MONEDERO 3584 COLOR AZUL'),
(3, '123452', 'ZAPATOS 835 TALLA 38 VERDE'),
(4, '123453', 'CARTERA GRANDE 5288 NEGRO'),
(5, '123454', 'ZAPATOS 342 TALLA 37 ROJO'),
(6, '123455', 'CARTERA GRANDE 5285 MARRON'),
(7, '123456', 'BUFANDA 876 NEGRO'),
(8, '123457', 'BLUSA 84126 TALLA MEDIANA AMARILLO'),
(9, '123458', 'CARTERA PEQUEÑA 7834 VERDE'),
(10, '123459', 'MONEDERO 3585 COLOR MARRON');

Si quieres buscar exactamente todos los productos, entonces necesitas AND
SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' AND
descripcion LIKE '%marron%';

1, CARTERA MEDIANA 521 MARRÓN
6, CARTERA GRANDE 5285 MARRON

Si quieres obtener todos los productos, independiente de si encuentra o no todos los términos, usa OR
SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' OR
descripcion LIKE '%marron%'

1, CARTERA MEDIANA 521 MARRÓN
4, CARTERA GRANDE 5288 NEGRO
6, CARTERA GRANDE 5285 MARRON
9, CARTERA PEQUEÑA 7834 VERDE
10, MONEDERO 3585 COLOR MARRON

Si quieres tener primero los productos que cumplieron todas las condiciones y luego los que solo cumplen alguna, puedes usar UNION con AND y luego OR.
(SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' AND
descripcion LIKE '%marron%')
UNION 
(SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' OR
descripcion LIKE '%marron%')

1, CARTERA MEDIANA 521 MARRÓN
6, CARTERA GRANDE 5285 MARRON
4, CARTERA GRANDE 5288 NEGRO
9, CARTERA PEQUEÑA 7834 VERDE
10, MONEDERO 3585 COLOR MARRON

Se puede complicar hasta el infinito si uno quiere, como última aproximación, podrías hacer un término obligatorio y que se cumpla al menos uno de los otros términos. Por ejemplo, si el usuario escribe cartera grande negro. Que el resultado tenga Si o Si, la palabra cartera y que se cumpla alguno de los términos grande o negro:
(SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' AND
descripcion LIKE '%grande%' AND 
descripcion LIKE '%negro%')
UNION 
(SELECT id, descripcion FROM productos WHERE 
descripcion LIKE '%cartera%' AND (
    descripcion LIKE '%grande%' OR
    descripcion LIKE '%negro%')
)

4, CARTERA GRANDE 5288 NEGRO
6, CARTERA GRANDE 5285 MARRON


[ Conclusión ]
Antes de programar en PHP juega con SQL, mueve las cosas hasta tener la consulta que necesitas.
A veces pasa que el resultado que quieres no lo puedes tener en una sola consulta. Para ello entonces te puedes apoyar de PHP, primero haces una consulta exacta y luego vas haciendo otras más inexactas.

excelente tu respuesta se entendio perfectamente. gracias voy hacer pruebas... Saludos.
